# How do I filter out an object with a given property?

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have an array with objects like
`const obj = [{value: 'prop1'}, {value: 'prop2', status: '401'}]`

How do I filter out that object with status property so that it remains only the first object in array?
I tried
`const result = obj.filter(o => o.status !== undefined)` but it doesn't work.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you use .find instead of filter? will it help ?

Comment: Change your condition to `item.status === undefined` in `filter` if you want to get object without status. It works as you wrote it just your condition is not right.

Comment: use this `obj.filter((o) => !o.status)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj = [{value: 'prop1'}, {value: 'prop2', status: '401'}];

let result = obj.filter( elem => !elem.status);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myArray = [{value: 'prop1'}, {value: 'prop2', status: '401'}]
const result = myArray.find(i => i.status);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will return first match, he wants to filter out with status, use filter

Comment: @Indraraj26 I'm not so sure - it's a bit unclear what OP wants

Comment: @Indraraj26 You're right, I wanted to filter out with status. Thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = [{value: 'prop1'}, {value: 'prop2', status: '401'}];

const newObj = obj.filter(item=> !item.status);
console.log(newObj);
```